# how to parse table information from website

Tags: c#, html, https

I want to process information found in the tables of this page: https://rl.insider.gg/pc and show relevant data on a website using ASP.NET MVC.

I have been able to find tutorials regarding parsing data from html tables, however, these don't seem to be html tables.

Am i missing something obvious?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string page = webClient.DownloadString("https://rl.insider.gg/pc");

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(page);

        var output = "";

        var table = doc.GetElementbyId("archive_regulation");

        foreach (HtmlNode td in table.Descendants("td"))
        {
            var anchors = td.Descendants("a");

            if (anchors.Count() > 0)
                output += anchors.First().GetAttributeValue("href", null);
            else
                output += td.InnerText;

            output += "\n";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);

    }
```

Comment: What articles have you been reading?  Have you tried the HtmlAgilityPack? https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: I have tried using that, but i can't seem to get it to work. But i haven't really used it before, so i might be doing something wrong, i can post the code. My current code however is not using HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: What makes you think they are not tables? Have you inspected the page in the browser? There doesn't seem to be an element with id archive_regulation when I looked.

Comment: I have inspected the page in the browser, and nowhere to be found was the element "table" or something alike.

Comment: there is an element with the id price_range as far as i can tell and i have corrected that in my code now. However, nothing is output still

Comment: which data do you want from html page. please provide element id from data to be extracted

Comment: @er-sho i want the name of an item, and the corresponding price range, from what i can tell, the elements have ids "priceRange" and "data-itemfullname"

Comment: @LasseFisker, I found 14 items with `priceRange` id and 772 items with `data-itemfullname` is so how this data should be map or look like

Comment: @er-sho i am going to be adding the price ranges, for a total price of the items in the designs that i'm gonna be posting on the site